# NavigationService in Windows Phone Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I can call NavigationService with a Btn_Click method

```
private void Com_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   string test = "Com";
    var x = NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/PageList.xaml" + "?msg1=" + test, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

But I can't call the same Service on this way

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    Test();
}    
private void Test()
{   string test = "Com";
    var x = NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/PageList.xaml" +   "?msg1=" + test, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without `var x =` :

```
  private void Test()
  {  
    string test = "Com";
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(@"/PageList.xaml" +   "?msg1=" + test, UriKind.Relative));
  }
```

Comment: Same error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object